# How to get file object using v-file-input in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have used Vuetify.js as Nuxt.Js's UI framework.
I wanted to get file object when I input file my apps.
So I used v-file-input component in Vuetify.Js
and I made code like below.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <v-file-input
            label="fileinput"
            multiple
            v-model="files"
            @change="getFileObject()"></v-file-input>    
    </div>    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue{
    files:any = []
    fileObj:any = {}
    async getFileObject(file:any){
        this.fileObj = await file
        console.log(this.fileObj)
    }
}
</script>
```

I checked the file object using console.log.
but 'this.fileObj' is undefined.
How do I get file object when I input files?
Could anyone advise me?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989162/file-upload-in-vuetify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@change](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#change) event has one parameter which the files array :

```
  @change="getFileObject($event)"></v-file-input>
```

then in script:

```
     async getFileObject(files:File[]){
         this.fileObj = await files
        console.log(this.fileObj)
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  I realized I need to put one parameter in event-handler like your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome, `@change="getFileObject($event)"` allows you to pass other parameters if you want, and `files:File[]` enforces the typing

Comment: I wanted to write like TypeScript to enforce the typing, but I didn't have any ideas to file object. I really understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the empty argument from the handler, it should be passed implicitly.  It should also be on `this.files` which is used as the input's `v-model`:

```html
@change="getFileObject"
```

```js
methods: {
  getFileObject(file:any) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(this.files)
  }
}
```